# Special handling of ConstraintViolationException after failed insert in JPA transaction

Tags: jpa, transactions

I want to do a couple of db-operations in a single transaction.
It should be rolled back on all failures but one: in the middel of all the db-ops there will be an insert statement which inserts a generated number into a field that has an unique constraint.
If this insert fails because the generated number is already present, in should be repeated with a newly generated number until it succeeds. But this insert should not affect the other operations.

Since there are no nested tx in JPA, i am not sure what the best practice would be here. i am wondering if this is such an uncommon case.

I tried it with an "embedded" tx, which is opened with requires-new that suspends the surrounding tx and resumes it after successfully inserting the random number.
That worked partially: if there is an exception in the surrounding tx, everything is rolled back but the random number insert.

If i use one single tx, I don't know how i should determine why this tx failed to commit. so i don't know if i have to repeat all the operations with a new random number or leave it because of another failure.

I also tried to explicitely flush the entity manager session after the insert to force the exception before i continue with the rest of the work in hope i could just delete that entity from the EM programmatically and try again.
But I didn't find a way to remove that entity from the EM after a failed insert?

I am also using Spring and SpringDataJPA.

```
@Transactional
public void doSomeThing() {

    SomeEntity fooEntity = new SomeEntity()
    someEntityRepository.save(fooEntity);

    someMoreDbOPs();

    RandomNoEntity rndEnt = new RandomNoEntity();
    while (true) {
            try {
                    rndEnt.setRandomNumber(generateRandomNumber());
                    entityManager.persist(rndEnt);
                    entityManager.flush();
                    break;
            } catch (ConstraintViolationException)
            {
                    //entityManager.detach(rndEnt); // didnt work
                    //entityManager.remove(rndEnt); // didnt work
            }
    }

    SomeEntity barEntity = new SomeEntity()
    someEntityRepository.save(barEntity);

    someMoreDbOPs();
}
```

i hope this pseudo code helps to describe what i am trying to do.

thanks in advance for any help...

Comment: Why use a random number rather than a number generated by a sequence, or even a UUID? What's the use-case. If you really need a random number, why does it need to be unique? And if you really need a random number, why not test if it already exists before inserting it, instead of inserting it and getting an exception?

Comment: actually i'm using a UUID. but if this application is running on more that one node it would theoretically be possible that the same uuid is generated multiple times? but event if that isn't the case or there are ways to prevent it, let's just use my question as a placeholder for "how are nested tx done the right way in jpa?" or "why it isn't possible to have nested tx in jpa?"

Comment: Not, it wouldn't. UUID means "Universally Unique identifier". The "Universally" part precisely means that two different nodes will generate different IDs, to keep the ID universally unique. The reason nested transactions are not allowed is that it would be impossible to guarantee that, after a "partial" rollback, the state in memory is rollbacked the same way as the data in the database. That's also the reason exceptions are not recoverable.

Comment: Another reason is that only JDBC supports nested transactions. So if you have a global transaction spanning two databases, or a database and a JMS system, both transactional resources would not be able to partially rollback.